# Vectorization of Pandas multi-line Expression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, numba

I have a 50,000 x 50 dataframe (df1) on which I run a multi-line expression and append the result into a new column.

The expression looks up a value in another dataframe (4000 x 12 in size; df2) and returns a string value.

The expression when applied via an anonymous lambda function takes around 2 minutes to complete on my not too old i5 laptop so I would like to vectorize but cannot work out how.

Any tips on how to vectorise would be much appreciated.  I've tried looking at numba.jit and numba.vectorize (or even just numpy vectorization but can't quite figure it out).

```
def myfunction(val1,val2,df2,col_name):
    #subset df2 before returning first value from passed col_name below
    df2_sub = df2.query('Col1 == "%s" and %d >= Col2 and %d <= Col3' % (val1,val2,val2))
    return df2_sub[col_name].iloc[0] #single string, I trap index errors in my real code using a try/except block

df1['new col'] = df1.apply(lambda row: myfunction(row['Col4'],row['Col5'],df2,'Col6'), axis=1) # this is effectively no better than a for loop
```

Comment: The good news is that this is a linear time operation, so it should be something that you can potentially vectorize with `numba`.  I can mostly understand what the code does by looking at your example, but can you post a sample input/output to play with?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to do my best with an anonymized code sample above to protect my client's confidentiality.  All my code really does is look up a string value in a 2nd data frame and append to the 1st dataframe in a new column, but row by row. From what I can see the killer bit of this is the first line of myfunction() which takes a string and a numerical value, that's the bit I can't get around.  Also myfunction() takes in df2 which also may not be the best way of doing it? Is there a way of vectorizing the .query() line?